# how to create an object from array based on a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects. The array can have objects with similar data.So I created a key based on the object's data, and trying to group them together based on the key. So the new data structure will be

`newObj = {'key':key, 'data': [{obj1}, {obj2}], {'key':key, 'data': [{obj1}, {obj2}]`

I have tried the following, but the value is not an array and the object is always the last one. How can I modify it so that I can get the above mentioned output?

```
getGroupedData(listvalues:any, adjustments:any) {
        var GroupedInstrumentsArray:Array<any> = [];
        var GroupedInstrDic:any;
        var key:any
        listvalues.map((instr, index)=> {
            if (instr.instr_type === 'I' && instr.instr_group_fin === 'Y' ) {
               key = instr.instr_ccy + '_' + moment(instr.payment_due_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD').format('DD_MMM_YYYY') + '_' + instrument.buy + '_' + instr.po_number + '_' + instrument.upld_ref_no;
                if (instr.type === 'P') {
                    key = key + "_p" + index;
                }
                instrument.key = key;
                if (instrument.key) {
                    GroupedInstrumentsDic =  {
                        'key': key,
                        'value': instrument
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        return GroupedInstrDic;
    }
```

How can I make the above `value` an array so that it will have all the objects with same key? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you also share sample data and expected output?

Comment: Your `newObj` example is invalid. Is it meant to be an array instead of an object?

Comment: `the new data structure will be` invalid

Comment: In java I would love to use HashMap in this case.

Comment: It's recommended that you name your variables in lower camel case (i.e. groupedInstrumentsArray) to differentiate it from classes/interfaces and thus avoid confusion.

Comment: why reinventing the wheel, try lodash/underscore:
_.groupBy(array, o=> o.key)